# Is it possible to hide the Nav Bar on a UISplitViewController?

Tags: uikit, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a very simple app that I want to use a UISplitViewController in. It's so simple that I don't want the NavigationBar visible in portrait because there is no navigation in the left pane. (I do want to show it in portrait for the Popover to appear from. However, I don't seem able to hide it. Is the top element even a Nav Bar?

I've tried both of these:

```
[[splitViewController navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

for(UIViewController* vc in [splitViewController viewControllers]) {
    [[vc navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

}
```

But neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try this:

source code:
https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/

it helpful for hide the nav bar on a SplitViewController